# Ignoring NaN in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to find the unique elements in a column of a dataframe which have missing values. i tried this: `df[Column_name].unique()` but it returns nan as one of the elements. what can i do to just ignore the missing values.
dataframe look like this.[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emLdk.jpg)

Comment: What does your input dataframe look like?

Comment: @ScottBoston i have added a snapshot of the dataframe in the question.

Comment: Your input dataframe in the snapshot doesn't have any missing values

Comment: @RileyHun I have added another snapshot. have a look.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try calling `.dropna()` right before your call to `.unique()`. A working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.randint(0, 10, 12)})
df.loc[2] = np.nan
df.loc[5] = np.nan
df['col1'].unique()
### output: array([  4.,   0.,  nan,   8.,   1.,   3.,   2.,   6.])
df['col1'].dropna().unique()
### output: array([ 4.,  0.,  8.,  1.,  3.,  2.,  6.])
```