# How to ignore Nan and perform calculation on Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Below is my Dataframe:

```
           DP1       DP2       DP3  DP4  DP5
OP1        NaN  0.786232  0.092335  NaN  NaN
OP2  18.782195  0.554774  0.244653  NaN  NaN
OP3  58.570527  0.743150       NaN  NaN  NaN
OP4  87.540171       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN
OP5        NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Using above dataframe I am calculating sum of offset using below cade:

```
sumOff = cumdf.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:cumdf.index.get_loc(x.last_valid_index())].sum())
```

But it shows error because of Nan value.
How can I resolve this.

Comment: What is expected ouput?

Comment: df = df.fillna(0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring NaN in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681776/ignoring-nan-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: How to ignore the Nan values? I don't want to fill. Whenevere calculation take place Nan have to ignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need remove only missing values columns with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.iloc[:cumdf.index.get_loc(x.last_valid_index())].sum()
sumOff = cumdf.dropna(how='all', axis=1).apply(f)
print (sumOff)
DP1    77.352722
DP2     1.341006
DP3     0.092335
dtype: float64
```

If need all columns in final `Series` add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
sumOff = sumOff.reindex(cumdf.columns)
print (sumOff)
DP1    77.352722
DP2     1.341006
DP3     0.092335
DP4          NaN
DP5          NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Its Working. Tank You.

Comment: c = ResampledDF.iloc[1][::-1].cumprod()[::-1]
            ResampledDF = ResampledDF.append(pd.Series(c,name='CDF')) This is my code to calculate CDF but it returns Nan and -inf values. Can you please check this?

Comment: @Devil - How should looks expected ouput?

Comment: Please refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485925/how-to-calculate-cdf-in-python-dataframe