# How to calculate CDF in python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have below Dataframe:

```
                    DP1       DP2       DP3       DP4       DP5       DP6  ...      DP13      DP14      DP15  DP16  DP17  DP18
OP1                 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  1.984582  ...       NaN  7.445081       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP2                 NaN  3.352522  1.947486  0.833274  2.085060  0.898013  ... -2.156338  0.862895  1.150826   inf   NaN   NaN
OP3           11.650615  2.202162  1.724781  2.355730  1.308264  0.977641  ...  1.675422  1.030201  1.192028   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP4           16.977332  2.168358  1.216076  0.910061  2.024265  0.910230  ...  2.930730  1.304237       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP5           12.872961  1.512182  2.044515  0.390772  0.900004  1.011990  ... -1.087320       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP6                 NaN  1.348129  1.475396  0.153781  1.910459  0.839901  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP7                 NaN  1.793057  0.814527  2.277154  1.257133  1.032616  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP8                 NaN  0.232742  2.726803  0.969646  1.227970  0.375313  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP9                 NaN -0.822340  1.966493  1.147438       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP10                NaN  0.207764  0.577137  1.531194  1.243140  0.799128  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP11                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  3.019366       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP12                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP13                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP14                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP15                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP16                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP17                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
OP18                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Weighted Avg  14.175524  1.914653  1.491014  1.261061  1.464702  0.937948  ...  0.605240  0.945967  0.576550   inf   1.0   1.0
CDF                 NaN      -inf      -inf      -inf      -inf      -inf  ...      -inf       inf       inf   inf   NaN   NaN
```

Here I calculated Weighted average and I am trying to calculate CDF but returns Nan and -inf values.
code to calculate CDF i used:

```
c = ResampledDF.iloc[1][::-1].cumprod()[::-1]
ResampledDF = ResampledDF.append(pd.Series(c,name='CDF'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with remove missing values with infinitive values is:

```
c = ResampledDF.iloc[1][::-1].replace(np.inf, np.nan).dropna().cumprod()

ResampledDF = ResampledDF.append(c.rename('CDF'))
```

Comment: my code generates Resampled dataframe (ResampledDF) randomly whenever i run the code.  Each and every time i need to calculate CDF. CDF will get correct sometime, but it returns nan and -inf values some times. How can i resolve it?